# final class without implementing interfaces can be creating by Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, algorithm, oop

This is a final class without implementing interfaces:

```
@Component("finalClass")
public final class FinalClass {
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

This is the test class:

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
        FinalClass finalClass = (FinalClass) ac.getBean("finalClass");
        System.out.println(finalClass.hello());
    }
}
```

It can run. 
The final class can not be extending, and it doesn't implement any interfaces. Why can Spring create it?

Comment: Spring need to inherit or create a proxy class for a component only when you applied any AOP pointcut on it (eg. manage jdbc transaction by using `@Transactional` annotaion). Otherwise it can just be a plain java object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because spring uses reflection to do that, which can overcome those limitations. That's why spring can create proxies over objects, that are final, reach to private members and so on.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks very much! So if we don't use AOP, Spring uses reflection. And if we use AOP, Spring will use proxy, and it will throw an exception.